What are the experiences and benefits of worshipping the mahavidyas?
Each of the mahavidyas have different physical features. Can anyone share what are the experiences felt by the practitioners while doing the sadhana or ashttotara nama japa of the mahavidyas, and what are the benefits . Do all these deities offer moksha only or other material benefits. Thank you.
